# sending sms using cron job and php

Tags: php, cron, sms

I have a question about my script for sending a sms reminder, my goal is to make a application that takes birthday info from a database and send a sms the day before... i've got the "sending a sms" part working, using a form.. but now i want to use it in a Cron triggerd PHP file.
I first tried sending a mail and this part is working, but now i'm struggling with the sms part.

It's the first time I work with a cron job and I'm a quite new to PHP..

the first php code is what's repeated with cron.. i thougt i could use the same code snipet to $_POST the nummer(number) and tekst(text).. as i used in the last php code..

thanx in advance!!

```
<?php

require('includes/global.php');
require('includes/voip.buster.instellingen.php');

/* ### This is working ###
$to = "**********@gmail.com";
$subject = "cron!";
$body = "Hoi,\n\n Cron Job test";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
*/
    #### this part is not working ######
$nummer = $_POST['+0031*******'];
$tekst = $_POST['this is a sms message'];
SendSMS($nummer, $tekst);

?>
```

The connection to the sms webservice:

```
<?php

function SendSMS($to, $txt)
{
$user = "*******";
$pass = "*******";
$from = "*******";

$txt = substr($txt, 0, 160);
$url = "https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?";
$url .= "username=".$user."&password=".$pass;
$url .= "&from=".$from."&to=".$to."&text=".str_replace(" ", "%20", $txt);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results = explode("\n", $result);

return $results[4];
}

?>
```

and this is the working part using a form..

```
if(isset($_POST['addreminder'])) 
{
$nummer = $_POST['TEL'];
$tekst = $_POST['bericht'];
$resultaat = SendSMS($nummer, $tekst);

}   

$smsreminder = "

<div id='smsreminder' style='width:707px; display:none; height:auto; border:1px solid #999; padding:10px; padding-bottom:30px'>

        <br/>           
        ".$addreminders."           
        <br/>


        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?companyname=".$name."&tab=smsreminder' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='comphash' value='".$reminder['edit_hash']."'>

        <label for='tocontact'>ontvanger</label>
        <select name='tocontact'>".$options."</select><br/><br/>

        <label for='tel. nummer'>tel. nummer</label>
        <input type='text' name='TEL' id='TEL' /><br/><br/>         

        <label for='message'>smsbericht</label>
        <textarea name='bericht' id='bericht'></textarea><br/><br/>

        <label for='addreminder' style= 'margin-left:50px;'>&nbsp</label>
        <input type='submit' name='addreminder' value='Add Reminder' />

        </form>
    </div>

";
```

Comment: You don't really supply what is not working. Do you see any errors in your logs for example? When running crons it is usefull to implement some logging so you can see what happens. Next to that also consider testing from commandline, for example with SSH, so you can see whether some output happens.

Comment: Load number and text from database... What's the question actually?

Comment: Waarschijnlijk heb je geen waardes in je $_POST als je het als cron job draait. De waardes voor nummer en tekst zul je dus uit de database moeten halen en die geef je mee aan je SendSMS functie.

Comment: @mark ik gebruik nu nog geen database.. maar zo zou die toch gewoon de tekst tussen '' moeten versturen ==> $_POST['+0031*******']; $tekst = $_POST['this is a sms message'];

Comment: @Op_Je_Plaatsman de fout zit hem in $_POST['+0031*******']; je vraagt om de waarde van '+0031***' maar deze heeft geen waarde. $nummer = '+31***' zou wel moeten werken.

Comment: ahh.. ja eigenlijk heel logisch, zat nog steeds met dat formulier in mijn hoofd.. THANX meteen ff uitproberen

Comment: @Op_Je_Plaatsman ok mooi! accepteer dan gelijk even mijn antwoord :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in :

```
$nummer = $_POST['+0031*******'];
$tekst = $_POST['this is a sms message'];
```

If you execute this script using a cron job $_POST will not be available, simply because you probably will do a GET request.

Second, you are asking for the post value of "+31***". You should use the right key probably something like $_POST['number'] or $_POST['message'] instead of a value.

Just replace the two lines with this and it should work:

```
$nummer = '+31****';
$tekst = 'this is a text message';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the strip of code that doesn't work...

```
$nummer = $_POST['+0031*******'];
$tekst = $_POST['this is a sms message'];
```

You have put the number and the text inside the `$_POST[]` for some reason. This would only work if there were a variable in `$_POST[]` called 'this is an SMS message', which wouldn't happen because it has spaces. To fix this, just take the `$_POST[]` out and replace it with

```
$nummer = '+0031*******';
$tekst = 'this is an sms message';
```

If you want to get it from `$_POST[]`, replace the text inside `$_POST[]` with the name of the input you want to get it from.

Comment: yess thanx!!! tried to much diverent things so i got stuck and got everything mixed up.. :P it's working now :)

Comment: @Op_Je_Plaatsman To notify to people in the future and other people that this post solves the question, you can click the checkmark below the number left of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cron job like this one:

```
0   12   *   *   * php path/to/command/execute_sms.php
```

This for example triggers the script from the php cli at 12:00 o clock (server time) every day .

However if you use a UNIX system you will first need to make the script executable with the fallowing command in order to make it executable from the cli:

```
chmod +x path/to/command/execute_sms.php
```